# When I use for loop i try to reassign value of a variable and use the variable again and ultimately, I've got the previous value of the variable?

Tags: javascript

I tried to repeatedly increase the value of the variable at the end of the loop and then use the increased value to produce an array, the variable value stay the same

```js
let chunks = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    let start; // and then use reassigned value 
    if(!start) start = 0 
    chunks.push(start);
    start += 5 // here I'm trying reassiang value 
  }
 console.log(chunks)
// result: [0,0,0,0,0] || expected [0,5,10,15,20]
```

Comment: primitive values (number, booleans, strings) are passed by value not by reference (they are copied)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the value `start` inside the loop, which is resetting its value each iteration of the loop. Move it to outside the loop:

```
let chunks = [];
let start;
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(!start) start = 0 
    chunks.push(start);
    start += 5
}
console.log(chunks)
```

Comment: Or just... `let start = 0;` and remove the `if` block entirely.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts good point, but I left it in there since that's a part of OP's code that's not broken, just unconventional.

Answer (score 0):

Just move it outside! A good explanation here https://dev.to/nicolalc/why-you-should-stop-declaring-variables-inside-a-for-loop-3npo

```
let chunks = [];
let start; // and then use reassigned value 
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){    
    if(!start) start = 0 
    chunks.push(start);
    start += 5 // here I'm trying reassiang value 
  }
 console.log(chunks)
// result: [0,5,10,15,20]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variable inside for loop. Move variable declaration outside the loop.

```js
let chunks = [];
let start;

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    if(!start) start = 0 
    chunks.push(start);
    start += 5 // here I'm trying reassiang value 
}
 console.log(chunks)
```